# How to find index of previous data that is higher than current value with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I'm looking for more simple and fast way to find difference between 2 time series values using pandas.

I have the following time series data:

```
a = [100, 20, 0, 10, 10, 50]
```

I'd like to know the way to get index of value that is the higher than the current value.

For example, `a[3]` is `10`.

And we move one step backward in order to search for higher value than 10.

`a[2]` is `0`, which is lower than `10`( == `a[3]`). So let's move to `a[1]`.

`a[1]` is `20`, which is higher than `10`.

So the answer what I want is 2, which is (index of `a[3]` - index of `a[1]`).

In case of `a[5]` ( == `50`), the answer what I want is `5`, which is (index of `a[5]` - index of `a[0]`).

All the results would be the following:

```
func(a[0]) = 0

func(a[1]) = 0

func(a[2]) = 0

func(a[3]) = 2

func(a[4]) = 3

func(a[5]) = 5
```

It would be very helpful if you suggest any hints about implementing this kind of function.

Comment: why is `func(a[2])` not 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your listed output is not consistent with what you ask. This function may be what you want.

```
def func(l, index):
   for i in range( index):
      if l[index - i - 1] > l[index]:
         break
   else:
       return 0 # return 0 if it never finds a larger number (loop completes)

   return i + 1 # this should be the distance
```

It searches backwards, and returns the distance to the next number which is larger (and zero if none exist)

`[func(a, i) for i in range(len(a))]` gives

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
```